# Using a math formula to get distance between coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm

SimilarityCalculatore

- getBestMatch(Map target, List options) : float

Neighbor

- attributes: Map
- description : String
- name : String
- getDistance(Map) : float

Im pretty new to Java and I cant even begin to know where to start in this, I may be in a little over my head

The nearest-neighbor algorithm involves finding the minimum Euclidean / L1 distance in n- 
dimensional space. Tell your parents you learned that in college, maybe that will impress them. 
Don't tell them that this is basic high school geometry or then they'll know this isn't that hard. 
We give you the length of the horizontal and vertical sides of a right triangle and you find the 
length of the hypotenuse.

```
a^2  + b^2  = c^2
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do `a^2 + b^2`? Your question is very unclear. What's the significance of those attributes at the top?

Comment: Where do you store **coordinates**?

Comment: Check out this distance formula http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Comment: What is the question? There aren't any question marks...

Comment: I also don't know what you're asking. Finding distance is easy and you stated it isn't hard so you imply that's not what you are asking. : / `double xd = pt1.x - pt2.x, yd = pt1.y - pt2.y; double hyp = Math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);`

Comment: Since you're after the `Neighbor` with the minimum of a set of distances, you don't need to worry about the square root, to find which `Neighbor` this is.

Comment: Sorry! Like i said I'm very green at this.The last block of text is from my instructor and the top 2 blocks are from the UML that was given to us. I'm supposed to write code to figure out distances with the classes above given a hash map of strings and integers. Its called find the closest neighbor and I guess the formula is the math involved in figuring out the distance by triangulating it. I just don't know where to start with the code.

Comment: You'll have to start with something. It is too early for us to be able to help. If the directions are so vague you're probably better off asking the instructor for clarification. Stuff like what the maps are supposed to contain, what the attributes are, etc.

Answer (score 2):

How about setting up two classes that mirror your descriptions? This is a super simplified example, but it might help you get started.

```
class SimilarityCalculator {
  float getBestMatch(Map target, List options) { /* ... */ }
}

class Neighbor {
  Map getAttributes() { /* ... */ }
  String getDescription() { /* ... */ }
  String getName() { /* ... */ }
  float getDistance(Map map) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Not sure how else to help based on your description.

Comment: Sorry! Like i said I'm very green at this.The last block of text is from my instructor and the top 2 blocks are from the UML that was given to us. I'm supposed to write code to figure out distances with the classes above given a hash map of strings and integers. Its called find the closest neighbor and I guess the formula is the math involved in figuring out the distance by triangulating it. I just don't know where to start with the code.